# Apple startup image work in webapp but not in UIWebView - iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, sdk, loading, web-applications

I've implemented a webapp for iPhone 4 , which correctly loads "apple-touch-startup-image".

I followed the Apple documentation : 320 x 460 pixels and in portrait orientation, which works well when I open it as a webapp (from Mobile Safari).
However when I try to open my webapp link from a very simple *UIWebView inside a native app* , it does'nt show the apple-touch-startup-image.

Is there any way to perform that, for the purpose of showing a loading screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I try to open my webapp link from a very simple UIWebView from Xcode app ,it does'nt show the apple-touch-startup-image".

The `apple-touch-startup-image` is only displayed when the page is loaded as a standalone web app. You'll note it doesn't appear when the page is browsed to in Safari, which is functionally the same mechanism that's being employed by the UIWebView.

Your best bet is to display the `Default.png` image over the top of the UIWebView. You can check that the UIWebView has loaded and hide the overlaid image once it has.

Comment: Thank you! i'll try immediatly and let you know!!